# Getting the most out of stacktraces when using Reactor

Tags: spring, reactor

When trying to write a spring(boot) application mostly entirely in reactive APIs, using Reactor 3.1.6, I've found that stacktraces quickly become almost unusable.

Generally I've approached writing reactive by having my public methods be `Mono` or `Flux`, and lots of private methods to use as method-references for nicely readable  streams (example)

```
public Mono<Foo> somePublicMethod(final Bar arg) {
    return Mono.just(arg)
               .map(this::internalTransformation)
               .flatMap(this::nicelyNamedInternalTransformationAsync);
}

private Foobar internalTransformation(final Bar arg) {
    // ...
}

public Mono<Foo> nicelyNamedInternalTransformationAsync(final Foobar arg) {
    // ..
}
```

Additionally I quite often will `switchIfEmpty` for stream control, or `onErrorResume`. Once I have more of a full application, where an event listener calls a service which uses other services, the stacktraces for errors wind up being just absolutely gigantic. Most of it is reactor boilerplate, and I guess I'm just bad at knowing how to actually chain streams together since actually figuring out the path through the stream calls is pretty darn difficult. Arguably that's been one of the hardest sells for my team to take an interest in it too.

Are there any style guides, or patterns, for programming with streams that will produce succinct & useful stracktraces for debugging?

For a specific example, is there a way to map/switch in a stream that would make it not include the upstream in the trace?

Comment: there is a Debugging section in Reactor documentation that can be helpful for you: http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#debugging
There are features such as collecting all operators information in stacktraces (with some performance penalty) and checkpointing. The stacktraces will still be gigantic, however, they will finally contain some valuable information.